# Calling a controller method from view

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

I have a method in my controller

```
public function download($filepath){

$download_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. "mediabox/import";
$file = $download_path + $filepath ;

if(!$file) die("I'm sorry, you must specify a file name to download.");
if(eregi("\.ht.+", $file)) die("I'm sorry, you may not download that file.");
if(!file_exists($file)) die("I'm sorry, the file doesn't seem to exist.");
$type = filetype($file);

    header("Content-type: $type");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=$filename");
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Expires: 0');
    // Send the file contents.
readfile($file);

}
```

In my view I have a link

```
<a target='_blank' class='download_dialog' onClick="???">
```

I want to call the download metho of my controller onclick event of the link .
Is it good to do so ?
How can I do it ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
<a target='_blank' class='download_dialog' href="<?php echo base_url();?>YourControllerName/download">
```

(and yes, you would need to be using the url helper for base_url) or use that url in some javascript onClick call, but I am unsure if this is the best solution for you.

Comment: what if the method is in my model ?

Answer (score 0):

It's always a good idea to refer to a documentation first:

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html

Answer (score 0):

Please look in to using AJAX calls. There are some great resources out there on the web and here is one of them:

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/simple-ajax-php-and-javascript